# Alert with pixel width of an element

Tags: jquery

I need an alert to show the width of an element in pixels. For some reason the code below dowesnt fire any alert.

```
  var myVar = #('#from-1 select').width();

  alert(myVar);
```

Comment: Is that a typo?  The shortcut for jQuery is $, not #.

Comment: Easy rep for all! Come get it while it's hot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is dodgy. Not sure what you meant, but

```
var myVar = $('#from-1 select').width();

alert(myVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var myVar = $('#from-1 select').width();

  alert(myVar);
```